# Replace &amp; with %26 in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have XML coming back from a search engine with nodes like so

```
<team>Some team name with &amp;</team>
```

I need to make a link of the team and while it might not be the optimal way it worked till I discovered that some team names include an ampersand

What I have is (team surrounded by double quotes)

```
  <xsl:variable name="teamend" select="concat(team,'%22')"/>
<a href="{concat('http://site/page.aspx?k=team%3D%22', $teamend)}">
  <xsl:call-template name="DisplayCustomField">
  <xsl:with-param name="customfield" select="team" />
  </xsl:call-template>
```

but if team contains an ampersand the link will be broken, how can I best fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are [several ways to do URL-encoding in XSLT 1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url+encode+xslt+1.0) (unfortunately there is no built-in function, though). Which way works for you depends on your XSLT processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this named template and call it before using the string in `team`:

```
<xsl:template name="replace">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="substring"/>
    <xsl:param name="replacement"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($string, $substring)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, $substring)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$replacement"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="substring" select="$substring"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replacement" select="$replacement"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, $substring)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

You can call it like this, and replace any substring with another:

```
<xsl:variable name="string-with-escaped-ampersand">
    <xsl:call-template name="replace">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="team"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="substring">&amp;</xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="replacement">%26</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

And use it in your code:

```
<xsl:variable name="teamend" select="concat($string-with-escaped-ampersand,'%22')"/>
```

As @Tomalak pointed out in the comments, since you are generating an URL you might have to deal with several other characters which need to be encoded. There are functions for that in XSLT 2.0, but in XSLT 1.0 you will be limited to templates or extensions.

Comment: An advice towards proper URL-encoding might be more useful in this situation.